# scp error: TERM not set when using scp with AWS

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS machine running and would like to transfer files from it to my local machine. Filezilla is successful in listing directories, but for whatever reason refuses to transfer files.
So I try it manually:

```
scp ubuntu@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/deep-photo-styletransfer-py/serial_example/best1_t_1000.png /Users/Me/Desktop/foo.png
```

And receive

```
TERM environment variable not set.
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 4: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
/home/ubuntu
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 85: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 88: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 91: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

When I run `echo $TERM`, I get `xterm-256color` on both my local and the AWS machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the main problem was caused by some commands in my `.bashrc` (`clear;ls;pwd;`).

The other errors/warnings relate to `bind` directives which should only be executed in an interactive shell.